# In the Lightning Page Editor, is there a way to manage related lists individually?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, page-layout, lightning, lightning-experience

We are trying to get an application to work within the new Lightning Experience.  This is a traditional desktop/browser application. In the application, the standard Opportunity object has several custom sObjects that are master/detail and are related lists on the layout.  For one of them the absence of checkboxes on the left side is a fatal problem to our normal workflow, so we plan to build a Lightning Component as a replacement grid for this, with checkboxes.

My question is about how to replace one of many related lists on the Opportunity layout.  I have worked with the new Lightning App Builder Page Editor, but it does not seem to be able to do manipulate individual lists. The whole set of Related Lists can be dragged on and off of the layout, but individual ones cannot be changed. Is that correct?

Given that limitation, what would be a good strategy for replacing one related list out of several (lets say 5)?  I am thinking that I need to replace all 5 grids, even the ones that are OK without checkboxes, because the new Page Editor doesn't let me separate the one that needs checkboxes from the other 4.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use the Concept of Tabs in the lightning App Builder for the ones with checkboxes

[image]

Also for users using Lightning experience ,how about new profile with a new page layout and that has all 4 .

Otherwise I agree you may end up building all the related list

Comment: We've added a tab.  The concern is that the "related lists" component (the light-green choice near the middle of the left-hand column in your picture) seems to only be useable for adding all or none of the related lists.  So the problem is that once we build one replacement grid, it seems like the "related list" component will contain the old one that we don't want.

Comment: The related list column comes from the related list on the page layout .If you assign a different profile for your user and drop only 4 of them all 4 should appear and the other one with checkbox you ca drop as a tab

Comment: I think that's the answer.  I can have a separate layout for Lighting that users can switch to.  That layout would only contain the related lists that we do not want to customize.